# Grouped bar chart with zoom and updateable data error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In this [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/yK3RYKIzECxwBuEKkJlg?p=preview) I've added a zoom functionality to the chart, however, whenever I update the data in the dropdown menu and afterwards zoom in, the rectangles get positioned in a weird way.

I suspect that it has something to do with improper use of a key function in `.data`

I've tried assigning a key function here:

```
        .data(function(d) { 
            return copy.map(function(key) {
                return {key: key + input, value: d[key + input]}; 
            }); 
        }, function(d) { return d.State });
```

but this makes the rectangles not update properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:** When you update the new data, on select change. 
You are not updating the `x1` domain.

Adding snippet below to the update function (post you make your copy object from keys), will fix this problem.

`x1.domain(copy.map(c=>c+input))`

working fiddle [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9807jkqnpBCxTH3BrVRV?p=preview)